# Why does express.static work with app.use but not with app.get

Tags: node.js, express

In my server.ts file the line

```
app.get('/example', express.static('somefolder'));
```

gives me a 404, whereas

```
app.use('/example', express.static('somefolder'));
```

correctly serves the 'index.html' from 'somefolder' as a response to requests to 'myhost/example'.

According to the express documentation these should behave exactly the same in cases of GET requests. Why does one work and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two methods differ (amongst other things) in how [`req.path`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path) is populated:

- for `app.get('/example')`, it's set to `/example/`
- for `app.use('/example')`, it's set to `/`

When using `express.static()`, this means that internally, the static middleware will translate the request path to different locations:

- for `app.get('/example')`, it will look in `somefolder/example/`
- for `app.use('/example')`, it will look in `somefolder/`

You can easily test that by creating `somefolder/example/` and copying the `index.html` file into it; when you do that, the `app.get()` route will work as well.